# Is there a way to show initalHeaderSortDirection for the sort arrows?

Tags: tabulator

There's `initialSort()` for setting the sort, but it doesn't indicate in the headers (if headerSort:true) what direction the sorting is. I would think something like

```
initialHeaderSort([{field:"string",dir:"asc|desc"},...])
```

Which is the same parameter list given to `intialSort()`?
Or a flag in the constructor to indicate to use the `initialSort()` parameters ?
(me personally) I wouldnt like (or want) this particular option, because the data is already sorted by the DBM, so I don't want to waste Tabulator's time in sorting data that is already sorted (even if it's approaching zero time wasted ?)

Or a property in the column definition? `headerSortInitialIndicator`?
I know the column has `headerSortStartingDir`, but thats for after the user clicks on the sort arrows.

Answer (score 0):

The ***initialSort*** setup will be reflected in the header sort arrows, there is no distinction between sorting and header sorting, they are the same thing, header sorting just allows you to trigger the sort by clicking in the header